# Best practise to format a hibernate date in angular

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, rest

what is the best way to format a time value of a JSON objects (in milliseconds) as a date and render this in the view. For some reason angular seems not to format this properly therefore the input field stays empty?

A hibernate entity will be returned as JSON via REST.

**Entity Account:**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Account extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
...
```

**REST WS:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upsert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Account> upsert(@RequestBody Account account) {
    Account response = accountAccess.upsert(account);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Angular Account Controller:**

```
    $scope.updateAccount = function(flow) {
    $http.post("rest/account/upsert", $scope.account)
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.account = response;
        $localStorage.account = response;
        toaster.pop('success', "Account saved", "Your data was succesfully saved.")
    })
    .error(function(error){
        toaster.pop('error', "Account not saved", "Your data could not be saved.")
    })
}
```

**Account HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                <input id="birthday" type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="account.birthday | date" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Include a date filter string (however you want to show the time) along with your date filter.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: You didn't tell what the JSON value of the birthday was. Make sure to confugure Jackson so that it serializes them the way you want (typically, as a milliseconds timestamp or as an ISO-formatted string, both being accepted by the angular date filter)

Comment: Pls check the code again. I am using the date filter dont i?

Comment: @ JB Nizet: the date comes back as a millescond timestamp right from the rest webservice. but still its failes saying that there is a formating issue. any other ideas?

Comment: This is how the account object looks like in chrome debugger:  active: true
birthday: 274140000000
city: "Essen"
country: "Austria"
created: 1451224964000
deleted: false
email: "admin@test.de"
id: 2
image: "a7.jpg"
lastUpd: 1452263854000
name: "Ugur Teker"
newsletter: true